# Is there a way to turn off "launch on startup" on P4EXP?

Tags: perforce

When I start my computer, the "Connect to Perforce" of P4EXP automatically opens. If I close it without connecting, it will later on open back up randomly when I'm browsing the explorer. I don't need to use P4EXP on most days so it's pretty annoying.
Is there any way to turn that of? I'd much rather connect manually whenever I need to.

Comment: This seems unusual. If you're running Windows 10, go to Task Manager-->Startup and see if P4EXP is listed. If it is, disable it.

Comment: It isn't listed there unfortunately

Comment: Startup directory?

Comment: There is nothing in "%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup", if that is what you are asking?

Comment: Yes, that is what I was asking.

Comment: One other thought--could it be running as a service? If it was running as a service and you don't have a default config set up for it, I'd think it would come up and ask.

Comment: I don't see anything in "Services" related to P4EXP or Perforce. But I'm not sure if I'm missing something, I'm not used to dealing with services.
Thank you for all the suggestions anyway :)